# Two 'add to cart' buttons using different attributes

Tags: ubercart

I am using Ubercart 3 on Drupal 7 for my website.

How am I able to have two "Add to cart" button on a product page that use two different attributes? So for example I can have:

(Buy the large version)
(Buy the small version)

Those two buttons match my attributes that I have set in the back, so customers can click on one of those and add the product to the cart directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A. Enable Ubercart Cart Links (part of core). 
B. Add necessary attributes and make sure you have a default attribute set.

With UC cart links, you can perform the add-to-cart functionality with many different AND DYNAMIC arguments. Without making a new add-to-cart button using Form API or complicated setups.

You can,

- Add any quantity of any number of products to the customer's cart, with specific attributes and options for each added product, if applicable.
- Display a custom message to the user.
- Track the click for display on a store report.
- Empty the customer's shopping cart.
- Redirect to any page on the site.

Basically you make a URL that will, when opened, adds given items with given parameters to the current user's cart.

```
cart/add/e-p123_a1o2
```

See above link. When opened, it will first empty the cart (`e`), adds product/node ID 123 to the cart(`p123`) with attribute of ID 1 (a1) and that attribute's option ID 2 (`o2`).

You can see a very good help instructions on help section of uc_cart_links module's admin page (admin/help/uc_cart_links) .

You can build the URLs using Drupal's [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) or [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) functions.

Put these snippets in your node.tpl.php file of the product node type (node--product.tpl.php) where you want to display buttons.

```
<div id="buy-large">
<?php
 print l(
      t('Buy the large version'), 
      'cart/add/'.$node->id.'_a101'
    ); 
  ?>
</div>
<div id="buy-small">
<?php 
 print l(
      t('Buy the small version'), 
      'cart/add/'.$node->id.'_a102'
    );
?>
</div>
```

if you are putting this code in a block or anywhere other than node.tpl.php or variants, change `$node->nid` to `arg(1)` . This `arg(1)` thing will only work if the button is being displayed in full content page. 
if you are placing these buttons in a View, replace `$node->nid` with the appropriate node ID by adding a node: ID field and tokens.
If you want to see attribute and option IDs, go to attributes page and you will see the attribute/option ID which is a numeric one.

Good luck!

Comment: Just to let you know this websites only allows me to award you my bounty tomorrow, but I do have this in mind :)

Comment: Hello again, just an update that the link should be actually "cart/add/e-p123_a1o2" since cart links module split the arguments using underscore "_", and then it works great! Thank you

Comment: sorry for that mistake. anyway great to hear that you got it working.cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, might be ideal if you edit that bit so others can benefit as well. Really appreciate that